# Gorm many-to-many relationship, permanent delete of record inside a for-loop not working

Tags: go, go-gorm

I have a join table that holds relationship between users and projects in my program.
I have an update endpoint that tries to add projects to users, if they are already not present, otherwise it will remove the correlation.
I'm not able to permanently delete the record.
I've tried to use both recommended methods

- Session(&gorm.Session{AllowGlobalUpdate: true})
- Unscoped()

```
// UserProjects join table for linking projects to users.
type UserProjects struct {
    UserID          uint
    ProjectID       uint
}

func updateUserProjects(db *gorm.DB, userID uint, projects []Project) error {
    for _, project := range projects {
        userProject := UserProjects{
            UserID:     userID,
            ProjectID:  project.ID,
        }
        dump.P(userProject)

        result := db.Debug().Create(userProject)
        if result.Error != nil {
            // record already exists in db, will be removed instead of being inserted.
            if result.Error.(*mysql.MySQLError).Number == 1062 {
                //if result := db.Debug().Session(&gorm.Session{AllowGlobalUpdate: true}).Delete(&userProject); result.Error != nil {
                if result := db.Debug().Unscoped().Delete(&userProject); result.Error != nil {
                    dump.P(result.Error)
                }
                fmt.Println("project was not inserted, but instead removed!")
                continue
            }
            fmt.Println("sql create error return")
        }
        fmt.Println("project attached to user")
    }

    return nil
}
```

```
mysql> desc user_projects;
+------------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field      | Type            | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| user_id    | bigint unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| project_id | bigint unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
+------------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Error when using `Unscoped()`
*WHERE conditions required*

And no error when using `Session(&gorm.Session{AllowGlobalUpdate: true})`

Answer (score 0):

gorm complains with `Unscoped()` because it cannot form any query to delete with your current `UserProjects` struct without a `where clause` (No gorm tags).

declare this with relevant tags, atleast primaryKey and Unscoped() delete will work.

```
type UserProjects struct {
    UserID    uint `gorm:"primaryKey"`
    ProjectID uint `gorm:"primaryKey"`
}
```

Comment: I did what you suggested, but still no permanent deletion occurs
`2022/11/19 14:09:24 /Users/jonmasson/Development/go/timeclock/models/user.go:128 Error 1062: Duplicate entry '2-4' for key 'user_projects.PRIMARY'
[19.515ms] [rows:0] INSERT INTO `user_projects` (`user_id`,`project_id`) VALUES (2,4)

2022/11/19 14:09:24 /Users/jonmasson/Development/go/timeclock/models/user.go:131
[17.891ms] [rows:1] DELETE FROM `user_projects` WHERE (`user_projects`.`user_id`,`user_projects`.`project_id`) IN ((2,4))
project was not inserted, but instead removed!
^Csignal: interrupt`

Comment: everything looks correct, none errors are thrown, but the deletion does go through in DB.